# How to replace a field by a shell variable being another field?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Consider the following code:

```
renamed_column='2
6
10
8
22
20
6-
18
8-
12
16'

array1='2 0.00000 -1.45191
6 0.81778 -0.63413
10 0.85020 -0.60170
8 1.40260 -0.04931
22 3.25781 1.80590
20 4.32051 2.86860
6 0.00000 -0.93906
18 0.07618 -0.86288
8 0.36922 -0.56984
12 0.71195 -0.22711
16 0.88517 -0.05389'
```

I want to replace the first field `$1` of `array1` with `renamed_column` using the `awk` command.

My attempt was based on using `awk -v v="$renamed_column" '{$1=v; print $0}' <<< "$array1"`but that doesn't work.

The desired output reads,

```
2 0.00000 -1.45191
6 0.81778 -0.63413
10 0.85020 -0.60170
8 1.40260 -0.04931
22 3.25781 1.80590
20 4.32051 2.86860
6- 0.00000 -0.93906
18 0.07618 -0.86288
8- 0.36922 -0.56984
12 0.71195 -0.22711
16 0.88517 -0.05389
```

Comment: Having the contents of `renamed_column` be almost identical to the first column of `array1` and so the expected output looking almost identical to the input `array1` makes this question much harder to understand than it could have been. If you used letters A through K (or something else easily noticeable in the output) for the contents of `renamed_column` it'd be instantly clear what it is you're trying to do. Naming your scalar variable `array1` also adds to the confusion - you should rename it to something more meaningful and not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v v="$renamed_column" 'BEGIN{split(v,r)} {$1=r[NR]} 1' <<<"$array1"
2 0.00000 -1.45191
6 0.81778 -0.63413
10 0.85020 -0.60170
8 1.40260 -0.04931
22 3.25781 1.80590
20 4.32051 2.86860
6- 0.00000 -0.93906
18 0.07618 -0.86288
8- 0.36922 -0.56984
12 0.71195 -0.22711
16 0.88517 -0.05389
```

There's lots of other ways you could do this, of course, the above is just showing how to do it by making minimal changes to your original command.

That above saves the contents of the shell scalar variable `renamed_column` into the awk scalar variable `v`, then splits the contents of `v` into an awk array `r`, then input line by input line changes the value of each first field (from `<<<"$array1"`) to append the contents of `r[]` indexed by the current line number as stored in `NR`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `split(v,r)`?

Comment: Please look up `split()` in the awk man page and that'll tell you what it does. Ask yourself what `v` contains and what `r` contains (hint - `v` is a scalar and `r` is an array). If you're still confused after that, let me know what it is you don't understand and I'll try to help clarify it.

Comment: If it was that easy to understand I would not ask here :)
Even though you answered my question correctly, I didn't understand how it works

Comment: I added an explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the data in the two files `array1.txt` and `renamed_column.txt`, you could do something like this:

```
awk -v replfile=renamed_column.txt '{getline x < replfile; $1 = x; print; }' array1.txt  > output.txt
```

E.g. if `renamed_column.txt` is your input data, abbreviated a bit

```
20
6-
18
8-
12
```

and `array1.txt` is the corresponding

```
20 4.32051 2.86860
6 0.00000 -0.93906
18 0.07618 -0.86288
8 0.36922 -0.56984
12 0.71195 -0.22711
```

then the result, in `output.txt` would be

```
20 4.32051 2.86860
6- 0.00000 -0.93906
18 0.07618 -0.86288
8- 0.36922 -0.56984
12 0.71195 -0.22711
```

---

If you have the data in shell variables like that (and insist on keeping it that way), you could use process substitutions (in Bash/ksh/zsh) to pipe the data to awk:

```
awk -v replfile=<(echo "$renamed_column") '{getline x < replfile; $1 = x; print; }' <(echo "$array1")
```

But if you're going to use awk, handling data in files would be easier.

Comment: Could you explain briefly what happened in this code?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC, `getline` reads a line of data from the given file (to variable `x` here, with the filename passed through `replfile`), and that's then assigned to the first field of the current line (from the main input), and the whole line then printed. What awk does in general is to split the input line into fields (`$1`, `$2`, ...) and then run the given commands.

Comment: @ikkachu you meant `awk` reads `rename_file` as a row line, not as a column field?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC, `getline` reads full lines, so yes, the script will take a full line from `replfile`/`renamed_column` and use that to replace the first field of the corresponding line from `array1`. That's what I read your question as asking.

Comment: @EnthusiastiC, I don't know what you mean. Where would you use that?

Comment: Why using `replfile=<(echo "$renamed_column")` without `echo`ing doesn't work?
that is, `replfile="$renamed_column"`

Comment: @EnthusiastiC, awk is geared to reading data from a file. If you have the data in a shell variable, it's not something awk can read. Hence the process substitution (`<(..)`) that makes the output of a command available as something that looks like a file. Multi-line shell variables aren't really very easy to process.

Answer (score 0):

According to [comments to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703413/how-to-replace-a-field-by-a-shell-variable-being-another-field/703469?noredirect=1#comment1330635_703469), the data is tab-delimited, not space-delimited as it appears in the question. The code below has been modified with this in mind.

Using `paste` and `cut` instead of `awk`, and assuming you are using a shell that supports here-string redirection with `<<<"..."` and process substitution with `<(...)`:

```bsh
paste - <( cut -f 2- <<<"$array1" ) <<<"$renamed_column"
```

This uses `paste` to create two tab-delimited fields read from the standard input of the utility and a temporary file.

The standard input, symbolized by the `-` placeholder on the command line of `paste`, is the first field and comes from the input redirection of the string in `$renamed_column`.

The temporary file is created on the fly by a process substitution and provides the second field processed by `paste`. The process substitution runs `cut`, which extracts all but the first tab-delimited field from the string in `$array1`, which it reads via another here-string.

If you have the data in files instead, just replace the here-string redirections above with the filenames:

```bsh
paste new_column_1 <( cut -f 2- old_data )
```

Comment: I used the first version of your answer. However, this appends the old `$1` field of `array1` to the output of your code where instead the `$1` field should be replaced by the new one `renamed_column` as is in the last part of the question.

Comment: Also, "which extracts all but the first space-delimited field from the string in `$array1`"
I'm still confused about what `cut` did to `"$array1"`? I run it alone, it returns the same `"$array1"`. Did you mean it should only extract the first field `$1`?

Comment: Are you saying `cut -d ' ' -f 2- <<<"$array1"` returns three columns? If so, your data is not using spaces as delimiters and what you are showing is not what you actually have.  Try copying and pasting the two variables from your question and test again. That `cut` command should result in the last two columns of your `array1` data.

Comment: It's my fault, the data is delimited by tabs instead of single spaces. Because I obtain `array1` by executing another command. I sufficed to show its content.

Comment: It's possible to edit your code to this one `paste - <( cut --fields=2- <<<"$array1" ) <<<"$renamed_column"` if both `array1` and `renamed_column` were delimited by tabs. And YES your code works fine, except that my intention was on `awk`. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: @EnthusiastiC Thanks, I have amended my answer although you would probably want to mention that the data is tab-delimited in the question too (it looks space-delimited there).  Note that `--fields` is a non-standard option to `cut`, which I believe is equivalent to `-f`, so I won't change that (`--fields` doesn't even work on my system).